# Storing datetime user input in list

Tags: python, list, datetime

**Background -**
 I am a novice, with a function who's objective is to take and store 4x user inputs in respective lists, before being used in other functions in my program.

**Problem -**
Whilst I have been able to wrap `entities_list` and `views_list` in [ ] to have them saved in lists, when I tried to apply the same logic to `start_date` and `end_date` and run the function, I got a `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not list`.

I attempted to overcome this issue by using `list()`. (e.g., `start_date = list(start_date)`). The problem with that approach, is that the list then outputs each character from the inputted date as individual values in the list. E.g. if the user enters `2020-01-01` the list is `['2', '0', '2', '0', '-', '0', '1', '-', '0', '1']`

How would I ensure that the list contains the complete user inputted date? E.g.  `['2', '0', '2', '0', '-', '0', '1', '-', '0', '1']` becomes `['2020-01-01']`. Thank you in advance for any hints!

**Code (complete function) -**

```
def user_inputs():
    while True:
        try:
            entities_list = [int(x) for x in input("Entities for API Call:\n").split(', ')]
        except ValueError:
            print("---ERROR: MUST BE COMMA SEPERATED VALUES---")
            continue
        break
    while True:
        try:
            views_list = [int(x) for x in input("Views for API Call:\n").split(', ')]
        except ValueError:
            print("---ERROR: MUST BE COMMA SEPERATED VALUES---")
            continue
        break
    while True:
        try:
            start_date = input("Enter time in this format yyyy-mm-dd")
            time=datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
            start_date = list(start_date)
        except ValueError:
            print("---ERROR: MUST BE YYYY-MM-DD FORMAT ---")
            continue
        break
    while True:
        try:
            end_date = input("Enter time in this format yyyy-mm-dd")
            time=datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
            end_date = list(end_date)
        except ValueError:
            print("---ERROR: MUST BE YYYY-MM-DD FORMAT ---")
            continue
        break        
    return entities_list, views_list, start_date, end_date
user_inputs()
```

Comment: What about `end_date = [end_date]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I ensure that the list contains the complete user inputted date? E.g. ['2', '0', '2', '0', '-', '0', '1', '-', '0', '1'] becomes ['2020-01-01'].

You could use the [join() method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) and then wrap the returned string in a list.

```
["".join(myList)]
```